# ChartJS dynamic line chart ghosting back to old data when hovered on

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I'm having an issue with my chart (using ChartJs) where once I've edited the data on a chart, if I hover over that same chart it occasionally glitches to show previous data.

I've googled the issue and I know that the resolution most of the time is to use `.destroy()`, but for whatever reason (maybe I haven't put it into the right place?) it's not working for me. My actual code is very long and complicated so I've taken some bits out and made the array randomly generated just to make it simple. The base issue should still be there.

```js
function genCharts() {
    var colours = ['#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149', '#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149', '#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149']

    var chartTheme = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['3.1', '3.2'],
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                xPadding: 15,
                yPadding: 15,
                titleFontColor: 'rgb(256,256,256)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(67, 183, 249,0.8)',
                displayColors: false,
                cornerRadius: 3,
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'PRICE'
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
    };

    var chartId = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

    var chart = new Chart(chartId, chartTheme);

    chart.destroy();

    chart = new Chart(chartId, chartTheme);

    var array = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    var array2 = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var newData = {
            data: [array[i], array2[i]],
            label: 'random number',
            pointStyle: 'rectRot',
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointBorderWidth: 5,
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(256,256,256)',
            pointHoverRadius: 8,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 8,
            borderColor: colours[i]
        }

        chart.data.datasets.push(newData);
    }

    chart.update();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='button' value='generate' id='button' onclick='genCharts()'>
    <div style='height:200px; width: 200px;'>
        <canvas width='10' height='10' id='chart' style='height:10px; width: 100px;'></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js'></script>
<script src='scriptOne.js'></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is not a correct way to destroy chart, the chart variable is a local variable and you are creating a new chart to the local variable and destroying that again that doesn't mean it has destroyed all other previously created instances. One of the solutions would create a global variable to hold charts and destroy if everytime when the genCharts() is called. Here is the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/srgw2y7m/

Hope it helps!

```
var chart;

function genCharts() {

  if (chart) {
    chart.destroy();
  }

  var colours = ['#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149', '#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149', '#ff3232', '#ff5731', '#ff9130', '#ffc730', '#fffb30', '#cbff30', '#7bff30', '#30ff55', '#30ffb9', '#30f4ff', '#42a3ff', '#6083ff', '#7760ff', '#c535ff', '#ff34fb', '#ff33aa', '#ff3276', '#ff3149']

  var chartTheme = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['3.1', '3.2'],
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        xPadding: 15,
        yPadding: 15,
        titleFontColor: 'rgb(256,256,256)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(67, 183, 249,0.8)',
        displayColors: false,
        cornerRadius: 3,
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'PRICE'
          }
        }]
      }
    },
  };

  var chartId = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

  chart = new Chart(chartId, chartTheme);

  var array = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
  var array2 = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var newData = {
      data: [array[i], array2[i]],
      label: 'random number',
      pointStyle: 'rectRot',
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBorderWidth: 5,
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(256,256,256)',
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 8,
      borderColor: colours[i]
    }

    chart.data.datasets.push(newData);
  }

  chart.update();
}
```

Comment: Also if you want to avoid using a global variable simply you can use the destroy all objects present in the `Chart.instances` object.

Comment: Wow nice! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `.destroy()` method correctly. When I encountered the same issue as you I ended up following other people's recommendation and destroying the entire `canvas` element from the DOM and re-rendering it.

I would alter your `genCharts()` function to look like this:

```
$('#chart').remove();
$('#canvasContainer').append("<canvas width='10' height='10' id='chart' style='height:10px; width: 100px;'></canvas>");

var chartId = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(chartId, chartTheme);
```

If you can figure out how to get `.destroy()` working correctly let me know! I would love to do it that way as well but couldn't figure it out for the life of me.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmp52046/1/

Comment: Thank you! I was considering doing that but I don't think it is the perfect solution. I'm not going to mark it as the answer yet because I'm sure there are negatives to doing it this way (stuff moving around on the page, animation glitches etc.) but if no one can demonstrate the correct way to use .destroy() I'll mark this as correct :)

Comment: I just noticed my link wasn't correct (again). I've updated it accordingly